Creating a new mathematical fisheye model
I've been using blender mostly for scientific research in computer science.
Right now, I would like to use a specific type of fisheye camera that was only calibrated with a specific mathematical model.
I know that Cycle allows to create fisheye camere with different parameters representation such as polynomial.
However, I was wondering which would be the way for me to code a new camera intrinsic model. Could I create a custom add-on? Would I have to modify and compile my own version of Cycle? Right now, I've only used the Script function of Blender to run Python scripts, but pretty sure this would not allow to do what I'm looking for.
Thank you for the help

If you want to code a new camera lens for Blender, unless you can do it with the current existing camera settings I doubt this can be done as a python addon, you would need to make your own Blender build from the source code an write new code in c++. Alternatively, you could also model the lens.
